# Make `%!` work in windows

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, shell, neovim-qt

I am on windows natively with neovim-qt .

I tried to use `%!python -m json.tool` on a valid json file .
It says `Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)` .
In powershell : `cat .\graphs.json | python -m json.tool` worked.

`%!python -c "import sys;print(sys.stdin.read())"`
return nothing

meaning, shell handing is problematic and no input.
The settings are `shell=cmd.exe` and `shellquote=` .

Advantage: If it would work with powershell.

Closely related to this:
[Make `!` work with powershell (neovim)](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/35132/make-work-with-powershell-neovim)
but didn't work out even after applying the solution there.

Comment: I have the same settings but I can't unfortunately reproduce your problem. You are referring in your question to powershell but ``cmd.exe`` corresponds to normal shell. Maybe could you set shell to ``powershell.exe``.

Comment: Did you try with neovim-qt? I tried now with `-- -u None `. `NVIM v0.6.0-dev+637-gafbf89dc0`

Comment: I would use `set verbose=5` and run the command that does not work. (N)Vim will show you what shell command is going to be executed. From there you can debug the shell quoting issues

Comment: Executing command: "python -c "import sys;print(sys.stdin.read())" < C:\Users\ekarni\AppData\Local\Temp\nvimiHi49d\1 >C:\Users\ekarni\AppData\Local\Temp\nvimiHi49d\2 2>&1"

Comment: It seems OK. But maybe stdin is empty. So is the case with json.tool. (Tried running it in bash). Indeed, `%!FIND /I "a"` works

Comment: next would be to run the same command from your shell

Comment: yeh, it doesn't work in the shell too

Comment: then this is clearly a problem about your shell.

Comment: what can be the problem with cmd.exe . This is more of a problem with python that didn't use the stdin correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is confusing. You talk about powershell not working with `json.tool`, but then you say your shell is set to `cmd.exe`. With cmd, you should have no problem working with `:%!` (I checked just now; it works). But with powershell/pwsh, there is a bug in both vim and neovim. I have a [PR open](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/19438) that fixes it. You should try that patch.

But before that, ensure you have set your shell properly. Just `:set shell=powershell` won't work. You have to follow `:h shell-powershell`.

```
let &shell = executable('pwsh') ? 'pwsh' : 'powershell'
let &shellcmdflag = '-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command [Console]::InputEncoding=[Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;'
let &shellredir = '2>&1 | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s; exit $LastExitCode'
let &shellpipe = '2>&1 | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s; exit $LastExitCode'
set shellquote= shellxquote=
```

---

About the PR: It fixes the shell command passed to powershell underneath the hood. As of writing this answer, in the master branch it's broken. Append `:4verbose` to `:%!` (i.e., `:4verbose%!...`) to see the exact command passed to powershell. If you run that command in powershell, it won't work. My PR fixes the [`make_filter_cmd`](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/blob/2a3cb0893b03aeff4d8c0b2116cbddda53bba5a2/src/nvim/ex_cmds.c#L1534) function which is responsible for building the exact shell command.

I had opened [another PR](https://github.com/neovim/neovim/pull/16271) in neovim, which *was* merged, but it only handled `:%!` for commands with one word, e.g., `:%!sort`.

Comment: I tried and failed with both. Will try again.

Comment: I meant both shells (cmd,powershell). Thank you for your contribution.

Comment: I don't understand why it didn't work in cmd for me and worked for you. Just typing this cmd in cmd doesn't work. So, I guess this is a python bug..

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit of a sad solution. After applying the powershell script, the following would Filter through and add the content.

```
function! FilterAll(str)
exec ":r !cat % | " . a:str
endfunction
```

Comment: I guess no one works with windows

Comment: What's a windows? ;)