# Make `!` work with powershell (neovim)

Tags: neovim, microsoft-windows, shell

I want to use `!` with powershell. I use neovim natively on windows.

I tried these settings

```
set shell=powershell.exe
set shellcmdflag=-NoProfile\ -NoLogo\ -NonInteractive\ -Command
set shellpipe=|
set shellredir=>
```

as suggested here https://robindouglas.uk/powershell/vim/2018/04/05/PowerShell-with-Vim.html

They don't work (having `nvim -u NONE` from cmd or neovim-qt).
They simply return the same command I typed.

I tried using this and additionally, set `set shellquote=\"` 
I get on `!ls`:

```
+ ""ls""
+   ~~~~
Unexpected token 'ls""' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Try `:set verbose=5` and see what actual command is executed by Vim. BTW: https://vimhelp.org/os_dos.txt.html#dos-powershell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I didn't notice it . There is actually in help `shell-powershell`

The settings are

```
        let &shell = has('win32') ? 'powershell' : 'pwsh'
        let &shellcmdflag = '-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command [Console]::InputEncoding=[Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;'
        let &shellredir = '2>&1 | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s; exit $LastExitCode'
        let &shellpipe = '2>&1 | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s; exit $LastExitCode'
        set shellquote= shellxquote=
```

Comment: What the hell :( It's too hard to decipher :(

Comment: Is the last = a typo?

Comment: No, it actually work

Comment: So you put this in an init.vim beside your init.lua?

Comment: I use .vimrc. Zz

Answer (score 1):

to add up to the above solution and since OP specifically asked about Neovim, you're most likely using an `init.lua`, so here's the Lua equivalent.

```lua
--[[
I'd personally get rid of the if statement altogether and just use 'pwsh',
since this makes it use Windows Powershell instead of Powershell Core
in the case you are using the latter. Since it's an equivalent I'll leave it
]]--
if vim.fn.has('win32') == 1 then
  vim.o.shell = 'powershell'
else
  vim.o.shell = 'pwsh'
end

vim.o.shellcmdflag = '-NoLogo -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Command [Console]::InputEncoding=[Console]::OutputEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8;'
vim.o.shellredir = '2>&1 | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s; exit $LastExitCode'
vim.o.shellpipe = '2>&1 | Out-File -Encoding UTF8 %s; exit $LastExitCode'
vim.o.shellquote = ''
vim.o.shellxquote = ''
```

Albeit personally, I prefer the `:term` command with a mapping instead to open a terminal in a split window, it's available in Vim 8.0+